# Cannot download kernel source code for rebuilding

Tags: kernel, source

I need to download kernel source code for rebuilding.
using command:  `sudo apt install linux-source-$(uname -r)`

It failed: E: Unable to locate package linux-source-5.19.0-32-generic
Is there a link to source code repository for downloading?

Thank you,

tiger

Comment: Try `apt-cache search linux-source`.

Comment: got source from git repository: git clone git://kernel.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-<release codename>.git

Comment: But I am confused and not sure which branch of code to use. Currently I have 5.19.0-43-generic kernel. Should I use Ubuntu-hwe-5.19.0-43.44~22.04.1 branch or from ubuntu-stable/ubuntu-stable-jammy.git, which only 5.13.0-43 version?